# '=' expected near 'g' neovim lsp config init file

Tags: lua, neovim

I'm trying to setup neovim config using lua config.

I want to use [vim-terminator](https://github.com/erietz/vim-terminator) to run current file.

I've my config file in this branch in the [repo](https://github.com/rajcspsg/nvim/tree/code_runner).

I've added the below config of vim-terminator plugin.

```
let g:terminator_runfile_map = {
            \ "javascript": "node",
            \ "python": "python -u",
            \ "c": "gcc $dir$fileName -o $dir$fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
            \ "fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
            \ }
```

I get the below error -

> ```
>   Error detected while processing /home/rajkumar/.config/nvim/init.lua:
>   E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: vim/_init_packages.lua:0: /home/rajkumar/.config/nvim/lua/v
>   im-terminator/init.lua:1: '=' expected near 'g'
>   stack traceback:
>           [C]: in function 'error'
>           vim/_init_packages.lua: in function <vim/_init_packages.lua:0>
>           [C]: in function 'require'
>   "." is a directory
>   Press ENTER or type command to continue
> ```

[image]

I'm novice in lua. Not sure how to fix this error.
Any Idea what I'm missing in my config.

Comment: This is not lua code, this is viml. To configure nvim with lua, at least go through [basic lua tutorial](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/lua/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let g:terminator_runfile_map = {
            \ "javascript": "node",
            \ "python": "python -u",
            \ "c": "gcc $dir$fileName -o $dir$fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
            \ "fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
            \ }
```

is not valid Lua code. `let g:terminator_runfile_map = ...` is Vim script.

If you require this file it is executed as Lua code and hence Lua would first complain about a missing `=` between `let` and `g` because an identifyer alone is not a valid Lua expression.

You're confusing two scripting languages here.

```
vim.g.terminator_runfile_map = {
  javascript = "node",
  python = "python -u",
  c = "c": "gcc $dir$fileName -o $dir$fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
  fortran = "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
 }
```

would be a Lua equivalent. I don't know if this makes sense in nvim context though.

Comment: Can't edit but looks like a typo -- `c = "c": "gcc ...` should be `c = "gcc ...`